# Sharepoint Online View in File Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

I have a client who would like to view in File Explorer, However they do not want to use Internet explorer.

Idealy I will be able to make some sort of app which automatically gets the authentication ?cookie/token/bearer? webdav requires without the users intervention. I dont mind if its a little console app that runs everytime windows turns on, or something along those lines.

Does anyone know what type of authnetication Sharepoint WebDav uses? 
Is it possible to create a script or program to automatically download this? (Headless Selenium with Internet explorer driver is 1 possibility, but that's extremely dirty, if even possible)

any other suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to sync the library. Just click the sync button while in the library, and that makes the library available in windows explorer via the OneDrive sync client. This isn't quite as ad-hoc as the older way, as individual libraries will need to be synced, and then later disconnected from syncing, as desired.

Comment: this was my first option, but it was taking upto 20minutes to sync a file, and client wasnt receptive to that. I ended up using a cript to automatically sync webdav client

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being a script which did exactly what I wanted:

https://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/onedrivemapper/

Every time the computer boots up, it re-maps the webdav drives and authenticates without Internet Explorer